# .NET client for the Google People API

Tags: api, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I do not see a .NET client for the Google People API here.

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/APIs

Do you know of any?

I need to get the user's full name, email address, gender and date of birth from Google using OAuth2. I could use it the raw HTTP way, but just to be safe, I want to use a Google provided client API.

**Update**

Hurray to hand-plumbing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google .net client Library can be found on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org), the plus package is here [Google.Apis.Plus.v1 Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Plus.v1/)

```
PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Plus.v1
```

I'm pretty sure it requires the latest version of Nugget to get it.

But I think you are going to have a small problem.  Not all of the information you are after is exposed in the API.  Sex and date of birth for example.

You can try it here [People.Get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get).  Scroll to the bottom: Authorize it then in userId enter "me" and it will show what the API can get of your data.

Comment: Hi @DalmTo, I read your website, too, in the process. Nice. :-) And thank you. I am using hand-plumbing now. You're right about the Plus API. I am going to use raw HTTP requests to People.get.

Comment: raw http requests to get data is doable but can get scary, if you have to deal with OAuth. The client lib makes it easer.

Comment: I understand that. I am taking my chances. I'd like to fall and learn, if I have to. :-)

Comment: I do the exact same thing I always start with the Raw HTTP requests then move on using the API its the only way to really know how it works.  Good luck

Answer (score 1):

All the APIs are available here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/

I'm pretty sure that one of the following APIs will make your life easier: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/plus/v1 or https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/oauth2/v2