# Fetching User Info like Name, Email using Google OAuth2

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using Google's .NET SDK in my application and would like to get the user info.
I have obtained the `UserCredential` object using the below scopes.

```
  new[] { Uri.EscapeUriString("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"), 
          Uri.EscapeUriString("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile") }
```

After this am looking for a `UserInfoService` to fetch the name and email of the user but it is not to be found.
Note I am only using Google's SDK and not handling the request and response myself.
I have found few samples in other sites but those don't use the Google API and are forming the
 request url and need to parse the response JSON.

Is there a way I can get the `UserInfo` without myself creating the request url and leave this to be handled by the Google API ?

Answer (score 2):

That was already asked before here:
[.NET client for the Google People API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759400/net-client-for-the-google-people-api)

Anyway, you should use the [OAuth 2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2/) library, and it looks like you will be interested in the [UserInfoResource.GetRequest](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/oauth2/v2/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Oauth2_1_1v2_1_1UserinfoResource_1_1GetRequest.html).